# Mercurial: Can I mix slashes and backslashes in paths?

Tags: mercurial

Are the following paths valid? Could they cause malfunction of Mercurial?

mercurial.ini file:

```
[ui]
ignore = ~\file/hgignore.ini
```

mercurial.ini file:

```
[ui]
ignore = .\file/hgignore.ini
```

hgrc file:

```
[paths]
default = D:\MySolution/MyProject
```

Comment: @Lasse: I don't want to do that. But I just cloned a repository, and found the default path of the hgrc file of a subrepo contains both slashs and backslashs, so I'm wondering if that could cause problems.

Comment: @Lasse: Also, sometimes I may accidentally mix slashs and backslashs in paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue in `hgrc`.

It can be an [issue in `hgsub`](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2644), for path to subrepos.